# How to Solve Eigenvector for Homogeneous Differential Equation when Eigenvalue Generates Zeros

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$
\text { Solve } \mathbf{X}^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{lll}2 & 1 & 6 \\ 0 & 2 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{array}\right) \mathbf{X}
$$

Characteristic equation is $(\lambda-2)^{3}=0$ with $\lambda_{1}=2$ as eigenvalue. The first task in solving first Eigenvector K, $(\mathbf{A}-2 \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{K}=\mathbf{0}$, the books provides
$$
\mathbf{K}=\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right)
$$

However for ($ A - \lambda I $) after elimination I get:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 \\
0 && 0 && 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
With that, $ k_2 $ and $ k_3 = 0$. But I don't understand where the 1 in the first row of K comes from.

Comment: Your matrix is not diagonalizable and there are no basis of eigenvectors.  Use generalized eigenvectors instead.

Comment: You do not need the eigenvectors to compute the solution, as with $A=2I+N$, $N^3=0$ you get exactly $e^{tA}=e^{2t}(I+tN+\frac12t^2N^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get $k_2=k_3=0$, so $k_1$ is arbitrary, and the eigenspace is
$$
V=\{(k_1,0,0)\in\mathbb{R^3}:\ \forall k_1\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
and are all multiples of $(1,0,0)$ that is a base vector of the eigenspace.

Comment: How do we know $ k_1 \neq 0 $?

Comment: If $k_1$ disappear from your equations, it means that $k_1$ can get any possible value. See edit

Answer (score 0):

As any multiple of an Eigenvector is also an Eigenvector, you can assign $k_1$ any nonzerovalue, such as $1$.